# Cannot read property `_root` of undefined on Native Base ActionSheet

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, native-base

I'm wrapping my main App component in a Native Base `<Root>` as the docs suggest.

It looks like this:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import { Root } from 'native-base';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

const RootApp = () => (
    <Root>
        <App />
    </Root>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RootApp);
```

Then i'm trying to trigger the ActionSheet like this:

```
<Button transparent onPress={
     () => ActionSheet.show({
       options: this.BUTTONS,
       cancelButtonIndex: this.CANCEL_INDEX,
       destructiveButtonIndex: this.DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX,
       title: i18n.t("settings")
     },
       buttonIndex => {
          alert('Logout was clicked ' + buttonIndex);
       }
     )}>
</Button>
```

And it throws `Cannot read property _root of undefined`

I although would like to have the Button to call it like this:

```
<Button onPress={ () => this.openSettings }></Button
```

And openSettings function looking like this:

```
openSettings() {
    ActionSheet.show({
            options: this.BUTTONS,
            cancelButtonIndex: this.CANCEL_INDEX,
            destructiveButtonIndex: this.DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX,
            title: i18n.t("settings")
        },
        buttonIndex => {

            alert('Logout was clicked ' + buttonIndex);
        }
    )
}
```

But again, didn't work.

Any suggestions?

```
React-Native version: 0.57.8
Native-Base version: ^2.10.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@msqar
I think it's an installation problem. there might be native-base not installed properly.

It's work properly in my project.
I'm going to share my code maybe it helps you.
go through it.

package.json looks like this.

[image: package.json]

index.js File

```
import React from "react";
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
import { Root } from "native-base";

const RootApp = () => (
  <Root>
    <App />
  </Root>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RootApp);
```

App.js File

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Button,
  Content,
  ActionSheet,
  Text
} from "native-base";
var BUTTONS = ["Option 0", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Delete", "Cancel"];
var DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX = 3;
var CANCEL_INDEX = 4;
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  openSettings = () => {
    ActionSheet.show(
      {
        options: BUTTONS,
        cancelButtonIndex: CANCEL_INDEX,
        destructiveButtonIndex: DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX,
        title: "Testing ActionSheet"
      },
      buttonIndex => {
        alert("logout was clicked" + buttonIndex);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content padder>
          <Button
            transparent
            onPress={() =>
              ActionSheet.show(
                {
                  options: BUTTONS,
                  cancelButtonIndex: CANCEL_INDEX,
                  destructiveButtonIndex: DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX,
                  title: "settings"
                },
                buttonIndex => {
                  alert("Logout was clicked " + buttonIndex);
                }
              )
            }
          >
            <Text>Actionsheet1</Text>
          </Button>

          <Button transparent onPress={() => this.openSettings()}>
            <Text>Actionsheet2</Text>
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

I have covered your both approach this code.

Screenshot of outputs:

[image: output1]
[image: output2]

Comment: Thank you for replying. Fortunately, it wasn't any of that but a misplacement of `<Root>` component. I had to put it on the topmost component inside the render function and that was okay already.
For instance: `render()  {return ( <Root><Container> .... </Container></Root> ); }`

Comment: Although I will mark your answer as the correct one for the time you took to help me :) Thanks again at least for worrying.

Comment: If I want to call function for let's say option 2 i want to call function "UnFollow"? how can I handle it? Should I check the index in `buttonIndex =>{ if buttonindex == 2 unFollowFunc()}` ?